# What time duration format is this?

Tags: time, format, duration, iso

I have some data saved as a tsv and the times it saves are as follow:

```
16984  = 16 second 984 milliseconds
214032 = 2 minutes 14 seconds, 032 milliseconds
```

I've looked at the https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html but it's not clear about durations

I don't think this is UNIX time either

It should from an https://imotions.com/ software

Comment: As far as I know, there really isn't a standard for durations.  Most likely you're going to run into seconds or milliseconds; the first of your samples is milliseconds.  However, as you've noticed, sometimes you'll run into weird formats like your second example.

Comment: ISO 8601-1 has §4.4 Time interval — §4.4.1 Means of specifying time intervals —
"A time interval shall be expressed in one of the following ways:
a) by a start and an end;
b) by a duration and context information;
c) by a start and a duration;
d) by a duration and an end. —
NOTE The time interval expressed by method b) is not fully determined by the information provided in the expression. It is assumed that, where needed, additional information to completely determine the time interval is available from the context. …".

Comment: It goes on to specify notations for durations, such as `PnnYnnMnnDTnnHnnMnnS` for durations.  Clearly, your notation doesn't match this, so it isn't a notation conforming to ISO 8601.  It can be used by arrangement between the parties interchanging data ("mutual agreement" in the standard).